# converting dataframe to list of tuples on condition

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I have following df:

```
    1         2         3         4 
1  NaN  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
2  NaN  0.027273  0.000000  0.000000
3  NaN  0.000000  0.101449  0.000000
4  NaN  0.000000  0.000000  0.194245
5  NaN  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
6  NaN  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
7  NaN  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
8  NaN  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
13 NaN  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
14 NaN  0.000000  5         0.000000
```

How I can convert it to list of tuples `[(column, row, data)]` and to take only values that are greater then `zero`.

for example I want to have following values:

```
[(2,2,0.027273), (3,3,0.101449 ), (3,14,5),(4,4,0.194245)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first cast columns to `int` (if necessary), [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and use list comprehension, where is necessary convert first and second value in `tuples` to `int` (default is `float`):

```
df.columns = df.columns.astype(int)

s = df.unstack()
tuples = [tuple((int(x[0]),int(x[1]),x[2])) for x in s[s>0].reset_index().values]
print (tuples)
[(2, 2, 0.027273000000000002), (3, 3, 0.101449), (3, 14, 5.0), (4, 4, 0.194245)]
```